# How to add static name in Choice Chip in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using this library `chips_choice: ^2.0.1` and displaying the api data on label (dynamically). The data i'm getting is "Apple" and "Banana" from API but i want to display "All" text first (static) and then the dynamic text coming from api. Below is the Sample dart code and along with model.
The result i want to display : "All" , "Apple", "Banana".

```
    class MenuPage extends StatefulWidget {
      const MenuPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
      @override
      _MenuPageState createState() => _MenuPageState();
    }
    class _MenuPageState extends State<MenuPage> {
    static late int menuIndex;
    @override
          void initState() {
            super.initState();
            menuIndex = 0;
          } 
    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
    child:Container(
              child: BlocBuilder<DishMenuTypesBloc, DishMenuTypesState>(
                  builder: (context, state) {
                if (state is LoadingDishMenuTypesState) {
                  return Center(child: PlatformCircularProgressIndicator());
                } else if (state is LoadedDishMenuTypesState) {
                  return buildDishMenuTypes(state.data);
                } else if (state is ErrorDishMenuTypesState) {
                  return Center(child: Text(state.message));
                }
                return Container();
              }),
            ),
    }
    Widget buildDishMenuTypes(List<DishMenuTypesDishTypes> data) {
return ChoiceChip(
                            label: Text(data[index]
                                .dishTypesLocales![0]!
                                .name!
                                .toString()), //getting "Apple" , "Banana"
                            selected: menuIndex == index,
                            selectedColor: redColor,
                            onSelected: (bool selected) {
                              setState(() {
                                menuIndex = selected ? index : 0;
                              });
                            },
                            backgroundColor: greyColor,
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: whiteColor,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
}
    }
```

> Model

```
class DishMenuTypesDishTypesDishTypesLocales {
  String? id;
  String? name;
  String? lang;
  String? createdAt;
  String? updatedAt;
  String? dishTypeId;
  DishMenuTypesDishTypesDishTypesLocales({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.lang,
    this.createdAt,
    this.updatedAt,
    this.dishTypeId,});
  DishMenuTypesDishTypesDishTypesLocales.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json["id"]?.toString();
    name = json["name"]?.toString();
    lang = json["lang"]?.toString();
    createdAt = json["createdAt"]?.toString();
    updatedAt = json["updatedAt"]?.toString();
    dishTypeId = json["dishTypeId"]?.toString();}
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data["id"] = id;
    data["name"] = name;
    data["lang"] = lang;
    data["createdAt"] = createdAt;
    data["updatedAt"] = updatedAt;
    data["dishTypeId"] = dishTypeId;
    return data;}}
class DishMenuTypesDishTypes {
  String? id;
  bool? isDeleted;
  String? createdAt;
  String? updatedAt;
  List<DishMenuTypesDishTypesDishTypesLocales?>? dishTypesLocales;    
  DishMenuTypesDishTypes({
    this.id,
    this.isDeleted,
    this.createdAt,
    this.updatedAt,
    this.dishTypesLocales,});
  DishMenuTypesDishTypes.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json["id"]?.toString();
    isDeleted = json["is_deleted"];
    createdAt = json["createdAt"]?.toString();
    updatedAt = json["updatedAt"]?.toString();
    if (json["dish_types_locales"] != null) {
      final v = json["dish_types_locales"];
      final arr0 = <DishMenuTypesDishTypesDishTypesLocales>[];
      v.forEach((v) {           arr0.add(DishMenuTypesDishTypesDishTypesLocales.fromJson(v));});
      dishTypesLocales = arr0;}}
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data["id"] = id;
    data["is_deleted"] = isDeleted;
    data["createdAt"] = createdAt;
    data["updatedAt"] = updatedAt;
    if (dishTypesLocales != null) {
      final v = dishTypesLocales;
      final arr0 = [];
      v!.forEach((v) {
        arr0.add(v!.toJson());});
      data["dish_types_locales"] = arr0;}
    return data;}}    
class DishMenuTypes {
  String? message;
  List<DishMenuTypesDishTypes?>? DishTypes;    
  DishMenuTypes({
    this.message,
    this.DishTypes,});
  DishMenuTypes.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    message = json["message"]?.toString();
    if (json["DishTypes"] != null) {
      final v = json["DishTypes"];
      final arr0 = <DishMenuTypesDishTypes>[];
      v.forEach((v) {
        arr0.add(DishMenuTypesDishTypes.fromJson(v));});
      DishTypes = arr0;}}
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data["message"] = message;
    if (DishTypes != null) {
      final v = DishTypes;
      final arr0 = [];
      v!.forEach((v) {
        arr0.add(v!.toJson());});
      data["DishTypes"] = arr0;}
    return data;}}
```

Comment: provide more code so we can help you

Comment: @AL.Sharie I have updated the code, kindly check it.

Comment: how do you add data to  `data[index]`?

Comment: @AL.Sharie `data[index]` coming from api, by the way i have updated the code but still the code i put very short.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add "all" to the beginning of the list

```dart
    Widget buildDishMenuTypes(List<DishMenuTypesDishTypes> data) {

    // put here your new object that contain "all" and the other info
     data.insert(0, new DishMenuTypesDishTypes(name:"all"));

     return ChoiceChip(
               label: Text(data[index]
                                .dishTypesLocales![0]!
                                .name!
                                .toString()), //getting "Apple" , "Banana"
               selected: menuIndex == index,
               selectedColor: redColor,
               onSelected: (bool selected) {
                     setState(() {
                           menuIndex = selected ? index : 0;
                         });
                     },
                backgroundColor: greyColor,
                labelStyle: TextStyle(
                           color: whiteColor,
                           fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
       }
    }
```

Comment: I have also added the Model because it is showing error `data.insert(0, new DishMenuTypesDishTypes(name:"all"));`

Comment: What i tried so far `data.insert(0, new DishMenuTypesDishTypes(dishTypesLocales: ));`

Comment: I put `name:"all"` because I don't know what data do you accept in your class. If this answer your question please mark it as accepted.

Comment: I agree but i want to insert `name:"all"` in `DishMenuTypesDishTypesDishTypesLocales` inside `data.insert(0, new DishMenuTypesDishTypes());`

Comment: How do i insert this in nested lists as per the models ?